# JDO getObjectById return null, why?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, persistence-manager

I just started using JDO and Google datastore
I have File class that contains code below for primary key.

```
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key key;
```

When I call this method, using ID/Name value in datastore, it gave me error - *javax.jdo.JDOObjectNotFoundException: Could not retrieve entity of kind File with key File("6298002603900928")*. 
But when I use Key value which in datastore, it returns the expected File object

ID/Name value is 6298002603900928
Key value is agxvcmdhbml6ZS1mcHZyEQsSBEZpbGUYgICAgICAmAsM

```
File file = null;
// get data from Google datastore
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
try {
    file = pm.getObjectById(File.class, fileId);
} catch (JDOObjectNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

I tried to convert ID/Name to Key by using this code

```
Key key = KeyFactory.stringToKey(fileId);
```

But it also gave me error *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Key PB: no elements.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why is there error.

fileId that I used is String. It is suppose to be Long.